# How do I close modal? Code was working, but now it is not.

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am making a portfolio website and want to have a table with previous projects I've worked on. The idea is to have a grid of thumbnails and when you click the image, a modal opens with the project in PDF. Everything is working out, except I cannot close the modal. The script for closing the modal was working before, but I'm not sure what happened. Neither the 'X' nor clicking outside the window are working. Any ideas?

```
<td><!-- AGNES HAMERLIK PROJECT --> 
                <!-- Trigger/Open The Modal -->
                <button id="agnes"><img src="../images/projectImages/agnes_thumbnail.png" height="250" width="auto" alt="Agnes Hamerlik Thumbnail"></button>

                <!-- The Modal -->
                <div id="agnesModal" class="modal">

                <!-- Modal content -->
                    <div class="modal-content">
                    <span class="close">&times;</span>
                    <object data="projectFiles/AgnesHamerlikPresentation.pdf" type="application/pdf" width="100%" height="400" alt="Agnes Presentation"></object> 
                        <p>
                            It appears your Web browser is not configured to display PDF files. No worries, just <a href="projectFiles/AgnesHamerlikPresentation.pdf">click here to download the PDF file.</a>
                        </p>

                    <p>Now to find out how to insert PDF of project </p>
                    </div>

                </div>

                <script> 
                // Get the modal
                var agnesModal = document.getElementById("agnesModal");

                // Get the button that opens the modal
                var agnesBtn = document.getElementById("agnes");

                // Get the <span> element that closes the modal
                var span = document.getElementsByClassName("close");

                // When the user clicks on the button, open the modal 
                agnesBtn.onclick = function() {
                    agnesModal.style.display = "block";
                }

                // When the user clicks on <span> (x), close the modal
                span.onclick = function() {
                    agnesModal.closeModal(); 
                    //agnesModal.style.display = "none";

                }

                // When the user clicks anywhere outside of the modal, close it
                window.onclick = function(event) {
                    if (event.target == agnesModal) {
                        agnesModal.style.display = "none";
                    }
                }

            </script>

            </td>
            <td><!-- VAN DOREN PROJECT --> 
                <!-- Trigger/Open The Modal -->
                <button id="vandoren"><img src="../images/projectImages/vandoren_thumbnail.png" height="250" width="auto" alt="Van Doren Thumbnail"></button>

                <!-- The Modal -->
                <div id="vandorenModal" class="modal">

                <!-- Modal content -->
                    <div class="modal-content">
                    <span class="close">&times;</span>
                    <object data="projectFiles/VanDorenPresentation.pdf" type="application/pdf" width="100%" height="400" alt="Van Doren Presentation"></object> 
                        <p>
                            It appears your Web browser is not configured to display PDF files. No worries, just <a href="projectFiles/VanDorenPresentation.pdf">click here to download the PDF file.</a>
                        </p>


                    <p>Now to find out how to insert PDF of project </p>
                    </div>

                </div>

                <script> 
                // Get the modal
                var vandorenModal = document.getElementById('vandorenModal');

                // Get the button that opens the modal
                var vandorenBtn = document.getElementById("vandoren");

                // Get the <span> element that closes the modal
                var span = document.getElementsByClassName("close");

                // When the user clicks on the button, open the modal 
                vandorenBtn.onclick = function() {
                    vandorenModal.style.display = "block";
                }

                // When the user clicks on <span> (x), close the modal
                span.onclick = function() {
                    vandorenModal.style.display = "none";
                }

                // When the user clicks anywhere outside of the modal, close it
                window.onclick = function(event) {
                    if (event.target == vandorenModalModal) {
                        vandorenModal.style.display = "none";
                    }
                }

            </script>

            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><!-- Platinum Sales Group Project --> 
                <!-- Trigger/Open The Modal -->
                <button id="psg"><img src="../images/projectImages/psg_thumbnail.png" height="250" width="auto" alt="Platinum Sales Group Thumbnail"></button>

                <!-- The Modal -->
                <div id="psgModal" class="modal">

                <!-- Modal content -->
                    <div class="modal-content">
                    <span class="close">&times;</span>
                    <object data="projectFiles/psgFINAL.pdf" type="application/pdf" width="100%" height="400" alt="Platinum Sales Group Presentation"></object>
                        <p>
                            It appears your Web browser is not configured to display PDF files. No worries, just <a href="psgFINAL.pdf">click here to download the PDF file.</a>
                        </p>

                    <p>Now to find out how to insert PDF of project </p>
                    </div>

                </div>

                <script> 
                // Get the modal
                var psgModal = document.getElementById('psgModal');

                // Get the button that opens the modal
                var psgBtn = document.getElementById("psg");

                // Get the <span> element that closes the modal
                var span = document.getElementsByClassName("close");

                // When the user clicks on the button, open the modal 
                psgBtn.onclick = function() {
                    psgModal.style.display = "block";
                }

                // When the user clicks on <span> (x), close the modal
                span.onclick = function() {
                    psgModal.style.display = "none";
                }

                // When the user clicks anywhere outside of the modal, close it
                window.onclick = function(event) {
                    if (event.target == psgModal) {
                        psgModal.style.display = "none";
                    }
                }

            </script>

            </td>
```

Comment: Do you know how to use the developer console in the browser you're using to test?  There may be JavaScript exceptions happening, which the developer console can tell you.  In Chrome, for example, one way to get to the developer console is to right-click any element on the page and select "Inspect"

Comment: Also, what did you change between when it worked and when it didn't?

Comment: What kind of library do you use? Where do you define the `closeModal` functions?

Comment: Did you try to replace `closeModal` function with `agnesModal.style.display = "none";`?

Comment: @Lotharyx Before, I was using the same variable names. For example... 
    var modal = document.getElementById('psgModal');  (***instead of var psgModal = ...***) but all the PDFs were the same document. So i went in and made them more specific to each project. Ever since changing that, closing the modal is not working

Comment: @2famous.TV I've tried both ways as seen above.